# C# Why isn't it possible to set the selectedValue of a dynamically created combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I create a combobox in a class and want to set the selected value for that combobox. But when I do that, the selectedValue stays null and when I try to set the selectedIndex I get a ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Code:

```
public Control GenerateList(Question question)
{
    // Clear the local givenAnswer collection
    _givenAnswer.Clear();

    // Get a list with answer possibilities
    List<QuestionAnswer> answers = question.GetAnswerSort();

    // Get a collection of given answers
    Collection<QuestionnaireAnswer> givenAnswers = question.GetGivenAnswers();

    _givenAnswer = givenAnswers;

    ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
    cmb.Name = "cmb";
    cmb.DisplayMember = "Answer";
    cmb.ValueMember = "Id";
    cmb.DataSource = answers;
    cmb.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

    // Check an answer is given to the question
    if (givenAnswers != null && givenAnswers.Count > 0)
    {
        cmb.Tag = givenAnswers[0].AnswerId;
        cmb.SelectedValue = givenAnswers[0].AnswerId; // answerId = 55, but SelectedValue stays null
    }

    cmb.SelectedIndex = 1; // For testting. This will throw a ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    cmb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cmb_SelectedIndexChanged);

    return cmb;
}
```

I hope someone can explain to me what is happening so I can understand why it isn't working.

Here is a complete little program what illustrates my problem. As you can see it doesn't set the SelectedValue, this stays null

```
namespace Dynamic_Create_Combo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GenerateControls gc = new GenerateControls();
            Control c = gc.GenerateCombo();

            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.Controls.Add(c);
            this.ResumeLayout(true);
        }
    }

    public class GenerateControls
    {
        public Control GenerateCombo()
        {
            // Create datasource
            Collection<Car> cars = new Collection<Car>();
            Car c = new Car();
            c.Id = 1;
            c.Name = "Car one";
            cars.Add(c);

            Car c1 = new Car();
            c1.Id = 2;
            c1.Name = "Car two";
            cars.Add(c1);

            Car c2 = new Car();
            c2.Id = 2;
            c2.Name = "Car three";
            cars.Add(c2);

            ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox();
            cmb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            cmb.DataSource = cars;
            cmb.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cmb.ValueMember = "Id";

            cmb.SelectedValue = 2;

            return cmb;
        }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _name;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public string Name 
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've set the value member to be "Id" but you're trying to use "AnswerId" as the selected value.

Without more details, it's hard to say why setting `SelectedIndex` is throwing an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` - perhaps the combobox is ignoring all values which don't have an "Id" property, thus giving you no values, so selecting index 1 is impossible?

EDIT: Okay, so it looks like it's only actually doing the binding when it becomes visible - or at some stage in the process. I've tried a few things to accelerate this, but they don't appear to help. What you *can* do is defer your selection:

```
EventHandler visibleChangedHandler = null;
visibleChangedHandler = delegate {
    cmb.SelectedIndex = 2;
    cmb.VisibleChanged -= visibleChangedHandler; // Only do this once!
};
cmb.VisibleChanged += visibleChangedHandler;
```

It's an ugly workaround, but it should at least help you to get going for the moment.

Comment: My combo it's ValueMember is Id, of type long. The AnswerId you referring to, is also of type long. I looks like the combo hasn't 'bind' the datasource yet. Because when I set the selectedValue on the actual form, it works. The problem is, I can't set the SelectedValue in the class, but I can set it on the form where the control takes his place.

Comment: @Martijn: It would be really helpful if you could add a short but *complete* program so that we could try this for ourselves. It needn't be complicated - but currently we're just guessing.

Comment: @Jon: Ive edited my startpost with a complete program with illustrates my situation.

Comment: @Martijn: That's not a complete program. Did you try compiling it with just the code you provided? Having added a `Main` method, removed the call to `InitializeComponent` and added the `using` directives, however, it compiles and runs without doing the appropriate selection... investigating.

Comment: When I run that code I get the exact same problem. I don't know what you mean. Why isn't this a complete program?

Comment: @Martijn: Yes, I get the problem too. It's not a complete program because I can't cut and paste it into a new text file, compile and run it.

Comment: Ah okee. But what do I have to do or can I do, to get this working?

Comment: @Martijn: I've just edited in a workaround. It's butt ugly I'm afraid :(

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. Despite it is uggly, I'm kind of new to this approach. If I understand this correctly you are unregistering the default visibleChangedHandler handler and replace it by your custom visibleChangedHandler? Which set the selectedindex (and unregister the default handler)?

Comment: @Martijn: No, it's not unregistering any existing handlers - it's adding a handler which sets the selected index, but then unregistering itself. The idea is this event handler should only fire the *first* time the visibility changes. It's "self-deregistering".

Comment: Thank for the workaround. But I it remains vague why the selected index can't be set in the class. Or is that because the items aren't drawn yet or something like that..

Comment: @Martijn: Not necessarily that they haven't been drawn - but the full databinding hasn't taken place. I don't know what prompts that, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 4):

This is just a guess, but maybe, the `ComboBox` doesn't bind the data in the `DataSource` until it's drawn. Check `cmb.Items.Count` in the line before the `SelectedIndex = 1`. If it is 0 try to first add the cmb to the `Form` before assigning `SelectedIndex`.

EDIT:

```
    public Control GenerateCombo() 
    { 
        // Create datasource 
        Collection<Car> cars = new Collection<Car>(); 
        Car c = new Car(); 
        c.Id = 1; 
        c.Name = "Car one"; 
        cars.Add(c); 

        Car c1 = new Car(); 
        c1.Id = 2; 
        c1.Name = "Car two"; 
        cars.Add(c1); 

        Car c2 = new Car(); 
        c2.Id = 2; 
        c2.Name = "Car three"; 
        cars.Add(c2); 

        ComboBox cmb = new ComboBox(); 
        cmb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList; 
        cmb.DataSource = cars; 
        cmb.DisplayMember = "Name"; 
        cmb.ValueMember = "Id"; 

        // add this: 
        EventHandler visibleChangedHandler = null; 
        visibleChangedHandler = delegate { 
            cmb.SelectedIndex = 2; 
            cmb.VisibleChanged -= visibleChangedHandler;
        }; 
        cmb.VisibleChanged += visibleChangedHandler; 

        // delete this: cmb.SelectedValue = 2; 

        return cmb; 
    }
```

Comment: The Item count is zero. When I add the control to the form I can set the SelectedValue (which I get from the Tag property..)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cmb.DataBindings and [this](http://bethmassi.blogspot.com/2005/04/combobox-databinding-woes.html) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because the combo is created during the Form_load event. Try to create your combo in the constructor and set the selection in Form_Load.

```
public class Form1
{


private ComboBox _comboBox1;
private Car _audi = new Car("Audi)");
private Car _porsche = new Car("Porsche");
private Car _vw = new Car("VW");

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this._comboBox1.SelectedItem = _vw;

}


public Form1()
{
    Load += Form1_Load;
    // This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent();

    // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    this._comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
    this._comboBox1.DataSource = {
        _audi,
        _porsche,
        _vw
    };
    this.Controls.Add(this._comboBox1);
}



private class Car
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;

    }

    public Car(name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`, and assigning the class that you want to it.  For example:

```
Car c1 = new Car();
// snip
cmb.SelectedItem = c1;
```

Since more than one item can have a value of 2 (as far as the `ComboBox` knows, anyway), I think you will have difficulty *setting* the value via `SelectedValue`.

Comment: I've tried this, but any Selected****(item, index, value) doesn't work.

Comment: It may be true that you are trying to add a value immediately after assigning a new datasource, but before that data becomes available in the listbox.

Try binding to the event `DataSourceChanged` and set the selected item there.

Comment: And should I register to that event before or after I set the datasource property?

Comment: I've tried both cases: before and after setting the DataSource property. I also tried DrawItem event, but none event fires..