# Winforms ComboBox can't set SelectedIndex while no form parent

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, parent

I have a strange problem with Windows Forms and I can't figure out how to resolve it.

The problem is, I wanted to create dynamicly a GroupBox with some components in it, especially with a ComboBox. It is working, but when I want to set the SelectedIndex of the ComboBox an ArgumentOutOfRange thrown. I have used Datasource property to set options to ComboBox. I have figured out, that the problem get resolved if I set the parent of the GroupBox first, but only if I set it to a Form.

So to summarize, ComboBox can't set SelectedIndex before it has no visual appearance

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    enum Example
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    }

    ComboBox cb;
    GroupBox gb;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        gb = new GroupBox()
        {
            //Parent = this,
            Text = "Try",
            AutoSize = true,
            AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowOnly
        };
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cb = new ComboBox()
        {
            Parent = gb,
            Top = 15,
            Left = 5,
            DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Example)),
            SelectedIndex = 1
        };
    }
}
```

I have written an example code with the same problem. If I comment out Parent = this when creating GroupBox, exception thrown, but If i reinsert it to code, it works fine.

How can I set ComboBox SelectedIndex before it get appeared? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if it's the Parent property. I would like you to try this. First set the DataSource, then set the SelectedIndex. Do not set both in the object initialization (inside the brackets).

Comment: You are not adding the gb to the Forms control collection. There is no need to set the parent

Comment: Don't mind my first suggestion. I actually tested your code into a temporary project. Commenting the Parent property has zero impact on your code. It executes and debugs without a problem both ways.

Comment: You need to add you controls to a Container: `gb.Controls.Add(cb)`, `this.Controls.Add(gb)`. A GroupBox can only be show when inside a Container Form (or another Container, a Panel for example. All these controls must be added to a Form's Controls collection, at some point).

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201340/c-sharp-why-isnt-it-possible-to-set-the-selectedvalue-of-a-dynamically-created

Comment: `I wanted to create dynamicly a GroupBox with some components in it` You might consider a UserControl instead.  It would allow you to create one thing rather than several and you could *encapsulate* the logic to manage the controls

Comment: Thanks for replies!

If I set the Parent property of the control, the control automatically inserted to the parent's Controls list, so it doesn't affect at all if I use Parent property or gb.Controls.Add and the same at GroupBox...

@ThymiosK - I have tested outside of it before I came here, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Steve - The link partly related, I have tried it, and there's no excpetion now, but the ComboBox's SelectedIndex reamin 0 now.

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain - Yep I think that will be the only way...

Comment: Try to set the SelectedIndex in the Shown event handler. It seems related to the point explained by Skeet in that link. Binding is done only after the control is visible. So it is logical to get an IndexOutOfRange when there is no datasource set until you have shown the control